# .simulate('click') only working when done twice on the same component, through ID and Class

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have gone through existing issues and could not find one similar to this.

I have a button element like so, that sits within a `<Contact/>` component that I am testing:

```
<div>
...
<button id="Contact-button-submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
...
</div>
```

and here is my test:

```
it('calls handleSubmit when Submit button is clicked', () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<Contact {...mockProps} />);
    wrapper.instance().handleSubmit = jest.fn();
    let { handleSubmit } = wrapper.instance();
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    wrapper.find('#Contact-button-submit').simulate('click'); // the only simulate click I want
    wrapper.find('.btn-primary').simulate('click'); // the simulate click I also had to add
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

The funny thing is that, when I only include the first simulate click (the ID one), the test fails at the last expect. The onClick function (handleSubmit) is never called.
But when I add the second one that uses className, it passes.

It seems like they BOTH need to be present. It will fail if one is removed.

Are there any known causes for this? I'm scratching my head over this.

Comment: did u console `wrapper.find('#Contact-button-submit').` and `wrapper.find('.btn-primary').`

Comment: yes, I did console.log(wrapper.find().debug()) with each.
They both came out with the same output

Answer (score 2):

the solution for me was to use `jest.spyOn`

```
it('calls handleSubmit when Submit button is clicked', () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.spyOn(Contact.prototype, 'handleSubmit');
    let wrapper = shallow(<Contact {...mockProps} />);
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    wrapper.find('#Contact-button-submit').prop('onClick')();
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

the issue was that I was stubbing the method after shallow rendering it, when in fact I needed to do that before.